# Letting users highlight text in a React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating an app where I'd like users to be able to select a piece of text in a paragraph and then edit it, the idea behind the app is the user will be correcting any spelling or grammatical errors in the document.

But I've hit a brick wall almost immediately, the documentation says the Text component supports `selectable` but setting that to true doesn't let me select individual words within the text, just the whole thing.

Is it possible to select an individual word or group of words and programmatically see what they've selected? I'm hoping there's something similar to what window.getSelection lets you do.

Comment: could look into [react-native-autogrow-textinput](https://github.com/wix/react-native-autogrow-textinput)

Answer (score 0):

I've had such a problem and used [react-native-zss-rich-text-editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor), which provides a method `async getSelectedText()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go!